# How to solve python moduleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-module

I'm having trouble understanding the module layout in python.  Here is my directory / file structure

```
Project2.1/
├── project2
│   ├── data_mining
│   │   ├── process.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── data
    │   └── data.csv
    ├── data_mining
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_process.py
    └── __init__.py
```

File test_process.py, contains the following import

`from project2.data_mining.process import ClassP`

Run file tests/data_mining/test_proecss.py using the following command from directory Project2.1

```
$ cd Project2.1
$ python3 tests/data_mining/test_process.py
```

Generates the error

```
  File "tests/data_mining/test_process.py", line 7, in <module>
    from project2.data_mining.process import ClassP
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project2'
```

ClassP is a class inside project2/data_mining/process.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in the data_mining directory of tests folder , only those files inside the data_mining folder are accessible directly, and you can't type the path of module with `from`, you need to add the path of the data_mining folder of `project2` , so get the exact path of data_mining (of project2 )

and

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(exact path)

from process import ClassP
```

this will append the path of that folder and make all files inside it accessible to the `import system`

also remeber we don't use `.py` or any extension while importing
it is just like importing any other module `from random import randint` for instance

:D

Comment: Thank you.  I generated relative path in test_process.py 
```
import os 
import sys
root_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/../..'
sys.path.append(root_path)1
```